# Transistor transimpedance amp design for photodiode digital input to arduino at 1MHz

Tags: arduino, transistors, digital-logic, photodiode, transimpedance

I would like to use a photodiode with an atmega328 to detect pulses of light from a toothed disk (illuminated by IR from the far side) at around 1MHz. Its to detect mechanical jitter in the rotation so I intend to time each 'illuminated' period with the atmega, the periods will be about 100 microseconds long so for 1% resolution I need to be able to detect them at about 1MHz.

I have not used photodiodes at a high speed before and it looks like its not as simple as I assumed - I need to use a transimpedance amp as the current is small and the speed high, and the capacitance of the photodiode causes problems as I understand it.

The device is meant to be battery operated at low current and 3v, and while I guess its possible to find an op amp to do this it seems like overkill, even though apparently split rails can be avoided - all I need is to detect the presence of a few tens of uA at 1MHz with a digital IO pin, seems like a quite basic requirement. Therefore I am looking at transistor transimpedance amp designs like this one [in another answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/630626). I realise many peoples instincts are to reach for a suitable op amp but thats not what my question is about today.

But there's no actual info there on what performance can be expected, and whether this circuit is optimised for digital operation. I don't need a swing of 10V but just enough to trigger the digital in pins of the atmega. I do need quite high speed considering the current available, which this answer says is achieved with low resistor values. But how to calculate the actual cutoff frequencies or gain at x frequency? Theres plenty of info on the web to do this with op amp circuits but I can't find the same for these simple transistor circuits.

Could one use a darlington type of approach for higher voltage / gain if the single transistor is not enough? Ideally since I have stocks of the the 2n3904/6 transistors would be usable.

I haven't chosen a photodiode yet - I do have a few [TPS703(F)s](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/211910/TOSHIBA/TPS703F.html) around, which are fairly fast at 100ns, but I can order others.

Since its battery operated, I obviously don't want to run the illuminating LED at too high a current meaning the photodiode current won't be at the top end of its rating (ideally), but needs must. If the only way to get it to work is to illuminate the photodiodes strongly then that can be managed, its just not as optimal as a midrange light level.

Comment: Is your goal to have 1 microsecond accuracy or 1 MHz bandwidth (350 ns rise time)? Those are very different things. I recently built an optical system for tracking ~10 KHz mechanical motion with a goal of ~ 100ps accuracy. I used a 25 MHz photodiode, which was plenty fast to sample a 10 KHz signal with good oversampling. Timing accuracy is about SNR moreso than bandwidth.

Comment: The key thing to decide is how much photocurrent you're starting with.  Assuming 1 MHz bandwidth and 1A/watt responsivity, that photodiode into 3500 ohms will generate 3.3V for an illumination power of less than 1 mW without an amplifier.  If you were ok with a 1 microsecond risetime (probably still better than you need), then you could use 10k ohm and would only need ~330 uW onto the photodiode.  If your system isn't too optically lossy then you might skip the amp entirely while not using very much power on the LED.

Comment: I'd be tempted to try something very simple:  driver your LED at some reasonable current, maybe 20 mA and put a small lens to focus onto the photodiode.  Then reverse bias the diode at 5V, and add resistance in series with the diode (to turn photocurrent into voltage) until your MCU detects the edges.  Since your system will be essentially noiseless, even a very slow rising edge will have very little jitter.  You may find that a simple 100k resistor and one of those spare diodes is all you need to solve this problem.

Comment: Look up Phil Hobbs. He has a book, *Building Electro-Optical Systems: Making It All Work*, on the topic. But also [a paper titled *Photodiode Front Ends: The Real Story*](https://opg.optica.org/opn/abstract.cfm?uri=opn-12-4-44) that you can find and read. Also [*Getting Photodetection Right*](https://electrooptical.net/static/oldsite/talks/GettingPDRight11.pdf). His style is a matter of taste, but since I worked with him for a few years decades ago, he's my recommendation.

Comment: @user1850479 I've been trying to figure out how you got those numbers but finally realise, I think you're using a figure for current per watt of light thats 100 times higher than the photodiode I mentioned, maybe you could confirm this? The linked datasheet mentions around 1uA at 0.1mW/cm2 as far as I can tell. Does the rest of your comment still stand for those figures - or have I read the sheet wrong - or am I interpreting it wrongly? Theres such a difference in value that I wonder if I am missing something.

Comment: @periblepsis interesting reads thanks - theres certainly some transistor utilising circuits there but they seem very high end! Impressive understanding the guy has though. Do you know of anything more basic? Playing around in ltspice with the basic circuit I linked to I seem to be able to get a fairly decent result on one edge at least (IE sharp 1MHz falling edge with far worse rising edge - fine by me though as I only need one edge). But I don't know if my model of a photodiode is right - just a 10uA current source 
with a 20pF cap across it.

Comment: Since photodiodes turn one photon into (slightly less than) 1 electron, they'll all generate slightly less than 1A (6x10^18 electrons per second) per 1 Watt (5.8 x 10^18 photons) at 1000nm.  Some datasheets print that for clarity, but a lot just assume you know the numbers in the SI units.  Anyway, you can check my math, but since you want a pretty slow rise time and aren't very light limited, I would first try with no amplifier at all.  That will give you the least noise and thus the least uncertainty in timing if you can make it work.

Comment: If the datasheets 1uA at 0.1mW/cm2 (1% of the light that a 1 cm2 photodiode would receive at that intensity), then it is probably 1 mm^2 photodiode, which is about right given the speed you mention.

Comment: @user1850479 I get it now re the photodiode area vs the figure per sq cm. Given my photodiode area can I really expect to get 3.3V into 3k5 with a focused ir diode running at 20mA? Because if so yea for sure I will set that up and try it, sounds great. But if the type of photodiode I am using is different to that assumed in your comment then I guess its not going to work. That said you still recommend trying it so I'm assuming you still think it could work out. Re the math, I am thinking 10uA through 3k5 will drop 35mV. Where am I going wrong? Can you tell me how you worked this out? Thx

Comment: The calculations above are for the diode you linked. I asked you how much photocurrent you would have since I don't know what your setup looks like. If you don't know, you could try using the 10-100k resistors I suggested and then maximizing your photocurrent. If you can get enough, then you're done.

Comment: @Pete I know some. But something like this may either be very easy or very 'interesting'. Details matter. For example, there will be rise and fall times, but also phase delays which may be different on the rise and fall or the similar. Whether any of this is important and needs focus? I'm not sure. More information about the application itself (so that I can imagine independently on what's important) or writing a specification on your side so that I don't have to imagine would be important. A video of the entire mechanism might also help. I usually spend a day or two on-site and ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't have a complete answer to my question I think the comments above have filled in the gaps in my understanding enough to go forward now.

It will take me a while to try out the suggestions and my own ideas from increased understanding now, in the mean time rather than leave this question open I felt I should answer it (for now).

As @user1850479 suggested I can try a direct input to the atmega with some variable reverse bias and a resistor to develop some voltage. The papers suggested by @periblepsis also provided some circuits, although probably of a greater quality than I need - I believe I understand it more now and after making a few circuits in spice I believe for my application if the direct input approach does not work I can try feeding the reverse biased diode into the base of a NPN, using a 10k load resistor and sampling the voltage (omitting the resistor from base to collector from the linked answer schematic).

We will see but thanks for the comments.